# How to take a full screenshot capture in Android compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, screenshot

I am developing an android app using Jetpack Compose.

I have a simple page.
It has a one scrollable Column like:

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(it)
        .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
) {
    if (!dataMap.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        dataMap.entries.forEachIndexed { index, (key, value) ->
            val header = key
            val list = value

            Text(text = title)

            list.forEach { item ->
                ItemUi(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually the `dataMap` is not simple, it has nested list.
Anyway the size of the `dataMap` is limited, it's not that big.
So I just use Column not LazyColumn.

And I have a FAB button to share the screen.
I can write the code take current screen and it works fine.

But the problem is that it only takes a screenshot current visible area not the fully scrolled area.

My `takeScreenshot` function is here:

```kotlin
private fun takeScreenShot(view: View, dir: File): File? {
    try {
        view.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
        val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.drawingCache)
        view.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
        val dateText = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", Date())
        val imageFile = File("$dir/result-$dateText.jpeg")
        FileOutputStream(imageFile).use { fos ->
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fos)
            fos.flush()
        }
        return imageFile
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

and this is called with:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
    val requestPermissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            takeScreenShot(activity.window.decorView.rootView, activity.filesDir)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a library like https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Capturable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out [jetpack-composable-to-bitmap-image](https://mobileappcircular.com/jetpack-composable-to-bitmap-image-4ddea2fe3238)

You can inflate an unbounded AndroidView and use `drawToBitmap` to convert it into bitmap

```
@Composable
fun screenshotableComposable(content : @Composable () -> Unit): () -> Bitmap {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val composeView = remember { ComposeView(context = context) }
    fun captureBitmap(): Bitmap = composeView.drawToBitmap()
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            composeView.apply {
                setContent {
                    content()
                    /*...content...*/
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true)   //  Make sure to set unbounded true to draw beyond screen area
    )

    return ::captureBitmap
}
```

and from where onClick method is present, declare `screenshotableComposable` which you call from onClick with `screenshotableComposable.invoke()` and it will return bitmap

```
val screenshotableComposable = screenshotableComposable(
    content = {
        /*...composable content...*/
    }
)


onClick = {
    val bitmap = screenshotableComposable.invoke()
}
```

There is an issue with that you need to draw content twice, one which actually renders on screen and other which renders within `screenshotableComposable`

Comment: It is not working with LazyColumn

Comment: Lazy composable are not fully rendered if it's is larger than available on screen

Answer (score 1):

There is a new native way to do this in Compose starting from Compose 1.6.0-alpha01+: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers#composable-to-bitmap

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(padding)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .drawWithCache {
            // Example that shows how to redirect rendering to an Android Picture and then
            // draw the picture into the original destination
            val width = this.size.width.toInt()
            val height = this.size.height.toInt()

            onDrawWithContent {
                val pictureCanvas =
                    androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas(
                        picture.beginRecording(
                            width,
                            height
                        )
                    )
                // requires at least 1.6.0-alpha01+
                draw(this, this.layoutDirection, pictureCanvas, this.size) {
                    this@onDrawWithContent.drawContent()
                }
                picture.endRecording()

                drawIntoCanvas { canvas -> canvas.nativeCanvas.drawPicture(picture) }
            }
        }

) {
    ScreenContentToCapture()
}
```

To convert Picture to Bitmap:

```
val bitmap = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    Bitmap.createBitmap(picture)
} else {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        picture.width,
        picture.height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = android.graphics.Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE)
    canvas.drawPicture(picture)
    bitmap
}
```

Comment: It is not working with LazyColumn, the list can not scroll either